# Android RecyclerView : Setting a view at the bottom of each row of recyclerView.

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a view that works as a footer of each row of `recyclerView`. What I am trying to achieve is something like this.

[image]

The image represents a row of my `recyclerView`.and each box a different view.

For most of the part it is obvious but I am having issues placing the the view that is represented by the **yellow box** at the bottom of the row.

I have tried a few different ways for example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/colored_penal"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="128"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="mtr" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hospital_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hey, this is a dummy hospital"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hospital_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/hospital_name"
            android:text="At the end of the road" />



        <!--This is the yellow box view that I want at the bottom-->
        <LinearLayout                  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/waiting_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Waiting time: 40 mins"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/travel_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Travel time: 20 mins"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have used `alignParentBottom` as `true` yet the view is not getting placed at the bottom of the row. It makes sense that Android squeezes each row to make sure it looks like a recyclerView but than how to put something at the bottom?

I also tried setting up `layout_height="fill_parent"`  and `gravity="bottom"` for the `LinearLayout` (yellow view) despite knowing `fill_parent` is deprecated but it didn't work anyways.

Would appreciate any input helping me achieve this.

Comment: Can you just try putting the  android:layout_height="wrap_content" for the yellow box's LinearLayout, I think since you are using match parent for that layout it is not going to the bottom..

Comment: I did try that. Ain't working. Same results.

Answer (score 1):

I just optimized layout. You need to specify your own View Components and attributes like maxLines or textSizes and etc. Its layout-ready.

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

   <View
       android:layout_width="10dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   <View
       android:layout_width="100dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:padding="12dp">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           tools:text="Title"/>

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           tools:text="Content"/>

       <Space
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"/>

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           tools:text="Footer"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Good luck there

Emre

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you are looking for

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="128"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="mtr" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hospital_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hey, this is a dummy hospital"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hospital_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/hospital_name"
            android:text="At the end of the road" />


        <!--This is the yellow box view that I want at the bottom-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hospital_address">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/waiting_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Waiting time: 40 mins"
                android:textSize="8sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/travel_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Travel time: 20 mins"
                android:textSize="8sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/colored_penal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hospital_address"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```